# How to hide /msg command in console

Tags: minecraft

I'm trying to create a minecraft server on aternos. But I have a problem:

When I am in the console, I can see /msg commands. That's bad because I don't want to see what others speak and it would ruin the game. So is there any plugin or setting that can hide /msg commands?

Comment: close the console ? your question is too board. You should take a look to logger filter with Log4J's API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what Minecraft Server you're running.

If you're running one with spigot, paper, or any other that can add plugins; just search up and find a console filter Plugin like [this bukkit plugin](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/logfilter) or [this forge mod](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/console-filter).

This question is quite broad and I don't have much to work with. If you want to DIY then do as Elikill58 said; take a look at the log4j log filter, [this spigot thread](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/change-logger-filter.321915/) might nudge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like the `/msg` command on Hypixel. In this case Hypixel just renames the `/tell` command (see more information [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/tell_command.php#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20%2Ftell,%2Fsay%20for%20public%20message)). Into a `/msg`.

Your question is broad, but I would assume you are just making it so the `/msg` (or `/tell`) commands are private and other players cannot see them. On aternos servers, it is default for it to only be shown to the server owner/moderators a.k.a admins. Therefore there is nothing needed to be changed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).